# How to hide links in a pdf generated using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have a pdf that is generated using the [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gem. My problem is that i see the "download pdf" link  in the pdf also. How to remove that link from the rendered pdf? I read about css media types but dont know how to implement that. can anyone help? or is there any other way other than using css media types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using the `pdf` format to determine if the user wants a pdf version.  You can check if the request format is pdf in your view

```
<% unless request.format.to_sym == :pdf %>
  <%= link_to 'Download PDF', { format: :pdf } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: no i m not rendering with a pdf.erb file. i m using render :pdf =>"filename" to render the pdf. and i have match "my_controller/downloader/:file_name"=>"my_controller#downloader" in the routes. and my respond_to block has this: if params[:file_name] then render :pdf=>"file_name" end

Comment: hmm then you can use the same check in your view. instead of checking for request.format, check for presence of `params[:file_name]`

Comment: yeah me too was thinking the same. and its working. thx. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the wicked_pdf helper to load a css file

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "print" -%>
<div class="export">
 <%= link_to "Download pdf", "http://example.com/download.pdf" %>
</div>
```

and in your css file you can add code to hide those links under the css selector 'export' using

```
@media print {
 .export {
  display: hidden;
 }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Essentially, you could mimick Bootstraps display utility classes "d-print-none" with "d-pdf-none" and ensure only to load the PDF stylesheet for PDFs.